# Change div text with jQuery Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, toggle

When using `slideToggle`, how to change the Text close/show?
I did a simple one, but cannot get the text change back.

Here is what I did:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.open').click(function(){        
            $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).text('close');
    });
    
        $('.open2').click(function(){        
            $('.showpanel2').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).text('close');
    });        
});
```

```css
body{
font-size:20px;
}
#box{
    border:2px solid #000;
    width:500px;
    min-height:300px;      
}
.open,.open2 {
    width:450px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin:5px auto 0 auto;
    color:#fff;     
    }
.showpanel,.showpanel2{
    width:450px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto 10px auto;
    background:red;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">

<div class="open">Show</div>
<div class="showpanel">This is content</div>

<div class="open2">Show</div>
<div class="showpanel2">This is content</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the `is()` assertion method to check whether the panel is open or closed in the animation's callback and set the text accordingly - http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/7/

```
$('.open').click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
             link.text('close');                
        } else {
             link.text('open');                
        }        
    });       
});
```

Comment: Nice use of a callback function to check the visibility after the animation has finished and change the text accordingly, This is the best answer here :)

Answer (score 15):

Just add a simple if statement to test the text like so

```
$('.open').click(function(){

       $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');
       if($(this).text() == 'close'){
           $(this).text('Show');
       } else {
           $(this).text('close');
       }
});
```

Like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/2/)

Answer (score 10):

Not the prettiest of methods, but it does the job in a single statement.

```
$(this).text(($(this).text() == 'Close') ? 'Show' : 'Close');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use .toggle()

Here is [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/15/)

```
$('.open').click(function(){    
        $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');                  
    }).toggle(function() {
            $(this).text('Hide');
        }, function() {
            $(this).text('Show');
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

check this may be user question is solve [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/9/)

Comment: +1 for $(this).html('Show'):$(this).html('close'); I didn't know that

Comment: it means if div current html text is close then it will change to show and if it is show then change to close.. '?'  is ternary operator

Answer (score 3):

Here's an updated version http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/1/

You can simply toggle a class on close/open, perform a check for that class and change the contained text accordingly

```
if( $(this).hasClass('active') )
  $(this).text('open');
else
  $(this).text('Show');

$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/9EFNK/10/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.open').toggle(function(){    
        $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text('close');
}, function(){
    $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).text('Show');
});

    $('.open2').toggle(function(){

        $('.showpanel2').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text('close');
    }, function(){
        $('.showpanel2').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text('Show');
    });   
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
jQuery.fn.toggleText = function() {
    var altText = this.data("alt-text");
    if (altText) {
        this.data("alt-text", this.html());
        this.html(altText);
    }
};
```

Here is how you use it

```js
 
   jQuery.fn.toggleText = function() {
     var altText = this.data("alt-text");

     if (altText) {
      this.data("alt-text", this.html());
      this.html(altText);
     }
    };

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function ()  {

     $(this).toggleText();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-toggle="offcanvas" data-alt-text="Close">Open</button>
```

You can even use html provided it's html encoded properly