# set timer to slidedown and the button change after slideup

Tags: javascript, jquery

What should I put as after I surf the website and in 3 seconds later the ads will slide down from the top of the webpage, and the button name on that div will change to 'hide'. And after we click hide button, the ads will slide up and the button name back again to 'show'.

It's working for sliding down and sliding up and also the button HIDE and SHOW change successfully. But after the button changed back to 'SHOW' again. I clicked 'SHOW' button but it wont change back to 'HIDE'. and also i didn't set timer to slide down. because I don't know what to put as I can't find any answer on other questions.

This is my script for JavaScript and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showAds").click(function () {
    $("#ads").slideToggle("slow");
    $('a#showLink').text('SHOW');
     });
});
```

This is what I want to show and hide

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="adsBox">
         <div id="ads"> <img src="assets/images/ads.jpg" alt="ads"> </div>
         <p> <a href="#" id="showLink" class="showAds">HIDE</a> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
#adsBox { display:none };
```

and also i tried something like this. And it's still not working too.

```
$(".showAds").click(function () {
    $("#ads").slideUp("slow");
    $('a#showLink').text('SHOW');
    $("#ads").slideDown("slow");
    $('a#showLink').text('HIDE');
});
```

I know my coding is quite messy. Please guide me to the right direction. And sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button label isn't changing back because, in short, you haven't told it to. Your call to `slideToggle()` switches the visibility of the element back and forth, but your call to `.text("SHOW")` only does one thing...sets the text to 'SHOW', every time.

Try something like this:

```
$(".showAds").click(function () {
   $("#ads").slideToggle("slow");
   $('a#showLink').text(text == "SHOW" ? "HIDE" : "SHOW");
});
```

Which is to say - 'if the text is SHOW, set it to HIDE. If not, set it to SHOW'.

For your timer, use `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("ads").slideToggle("slow");}, 3000);
```

Comment: I tried your code and the button is not working at all. Because I want to make the button change from HIDE to SHOW and after slideUp, the button label will change back again.

Comment: The setTimeout is really works. But not working for the button label. I totally understand what you meant, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You want it to say 'HIDE' when the slider is down and 'SHOW' when it is up, correct? If so, change the initial name (the one in the HTML) to SHOW, to match the initial state of the slider. Or have I misunderstood your intent?

Comment: yes, you are correct. that's what I meant. I changed the initial name to 'SHOW'. And it still doesnt work. Am I still missing something? Could it be jquery.js problem?

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949338/jquery-toggle-text-change) It is working here for text change.

Comment: If yours is still failing, could you put the code into jsfiddle or equivalent and provide a link so I can take a look?